# Guardar id de una imagen cicleada (php/Javascript)

Tags: php, jquery

Hola soy nuevo en jquery...

Estoy buscando información de como guardar un id de una imagen cicleada luego de esto necesito tomar ese id y que la pueda usar en un formulario

Ej: tengo multiples servicios como venta de:
Tasones 
Platos
Vasos 
Etc.

Luego de eso al momento de tomar dicho id el formulario de tiene que enviar la cotizacion, eso ya lo tengo..

Agradeceria su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

En el controlador del evento click puedes acceder al elemento que ha sido pulsado a través de `this`.

Para acceder al `id` del elemento puedes usar el método `attr` ya que jQuery trata el id como un atributo más:

```js
$(function(){
  $('img').click(function(){
    var imageId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#imagenPulsada').val(imageId);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  border: solid 1 px black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="imagen1" alt="imagen1" />
<img id="imagen2" alt="imagen2" />
<img id="imagen3" alt="imagen3" />
<img id="imagen4" alt="imagen4" />
<img id="imagen5" alt="imagen5" />
<img id="imagen6" alt="imagen6" />
<img id="imagen7" alt="imagen7" />

<input type="text" id="imagenPulsada" />
```